# implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

This is my Controller code

```
if($university == "")
{
    $university = "-";
}else if($university[0] == ""){
    $university = "-";
}else if(isset($university[0])){
    $university = implode(",",$university);
}else{
    $university = $university;
}
```

How to pass argument in implode() ?

Comment: You passed the `implode` parameter fine, but the second argument must be an `array`, however, the second argument `$university` is not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed implode argument is ok but your second argument is not an array.

```
if($university == "")
{
    $university = "-";
}else if($university[0] == ""){
    $university = "-";
}else if(isset($university[0])){ 
    $university = implode(",",$university); //<-- This argument is not an array
}else{
    $university = $university;
}
```